# Why can't I access lexical variables through a typeglob?

Tags: perl

I don't understand why the example below fail (test 2). Why I cant access the variable bb from the *bb glob?

```
use Test::More tests => 4;

$aa = 1;
my $bb = 2;   # HERE!
local $cc = 3;
our $dd = 4;

is(${*aa}, 1, "$ \*aa should be 1");
is(${*bb}, 2, "$ \*bb (my) should be 2");
is(${*cc}, 3, "$ \*cc (local) should be 3");
is(${*dd}, 4, "$ \*dd (our) should be 4");
```

The output is

```
1..4
ok 1 - *aa should be 1
#   Failed test '*bb (my) should be 2'
#   at untitled line 10.
#          got: undef
#     expected: '2'
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 4.
not ok 2 - *bb (my) should be 2
ok 3 - *cc (local) should be 3
ok 4 - *dd (our) should be 4
```

Under perl 5.16.0

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lexical variables (those created with `my`) are not part of the symbol table, so they cannot be reached by *globs*. See also [Of Symbol Tables and Globs](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=211441).

Comment: `local` just assigns a temporary value to a global variable.

Comment: `local` doesn't create variables. `local` saves the value of a package variable, hash element or array element and restores it on scope exit.